# Using the battery of an old, out-of-order laptop

Tags: lipo

I have a LiPo c31n1330 battery pack from my old asus laptop. Is it possible to use it in a safe way, outside of the laptop, for something like a raspberry-pi? If it is, how should I do it? I can see a group of 8 wires coming out of the pack. From left to right, there are:

1. three red wires
2. one white wire
3. one yellow wire
4. three black wires

Which one is for charging, and which one I can use to draw power from?
What safety measures should I follow?
The pack is completely intact and the battery used to run for quite some time before it needed to be recharged when the laptop was still working.
Thank you very much for any guidance.

Comment: `From left to right` has no meaning

Comment: I would suggest not doing it. It is possible to make a mistook and have a brilliant read flame assuming Li.  Batteries are inexpensive enough  you can just get a new set of cells. It may be possible to salvage the cells in this battery but at this point there condition or type is unknown.

Comment: Thanks Gil. Good to know about the risks